# php time counting days counting is wrong

Tags: php, time

```
function time2str($ts)
{
    if(!ctype_digit($ts))
        $ts = strtotime($ts);

    $diff = time() - $ts;
    if($diff == 0)
        return 'now';
    elseif($diff > 0)
    {
        $day_diff = floor($diff / 86400);
        if($day_diff == 0)
        {
            if($diff < 60) return 'just now';
            if($diff < 120) return '1 minute ago';
            if($diff < 3600) return floor($diff / 60) . ' minutes ago';
            if($diff < 7200) return '1 hour ago';
            if($diff < 86400) return floor($diff / 3600) . ' hours ago';
        }
        if($day_diff == 1) return 'Yesterday';
        if($day_diff < 7) return $day_diff . ' days ago';
        if($day_diff < 31) return ceil($day_diff / 7) . ' weeks ago';
        if($day_diff < 60) return 'last month';
        return date('F Y', $ts);
    }
    else
    {
        $diff = abs($diff);
        $day_diff = floor($diff / 86400);
        if($day_diff == 0)
        {
            if($diff < 120) return 'in a minute';
            if($diff < 3600) return 'in ' . floor($diff / 60) . ' minutes';
            if($diff < 7200) return 'in an hour';
            if($diff < 86400) return 'in ' . floor($diff / 3600) . ' hours';
        }
        if($day_diff == 1) return 'Tomorrow';
        if($day_diff < 4) return date('l', $ts);
        if($day_diff < 7 + (7 - date('w'))) return 'next week';
        if(ceil($day_diff / 7) < 4) return 'in ' . ceil($day_diff / 7) . ' weeks';
        if(date('n', $ts) == date('n') + 1) return 'next month';
        return date('F Y', $ts);
    }
}
```

I'm using this code, everything is alright, but if the date is (example)

`now 2015-12-19 04:22`

`post time 2015-12-18 23:59`

It's showing not yesterday but, 6 hours ago, how can I fix this? thanks

Comment: Calculate it by hand. Between those two times you showed, there are 15,780 seconds.. which should make the output 4 hours ago based on the logic in your code. Since you calculate "yesterday" to be a full 24 hours ago, you can't get the result you are asking for without changing the logic within your code to something that will differentiate between physical "days".

Comment: adding @Jon comment. With 15,780 seconds difference, push it to `$day_diff = floor($diff / 86400);` will return `0` (zero).  That is why you get the `if($diff < 86400) return floor($diff / 3600) . ' hours ago';` (6h ago)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Jon on my answer, I should have read more carefully

Comment: so how i understand, this code is useful, i can`t make that what i want from this code?

Comment: why you don't try subtract the only date without the time, if not same dates and different times < 86400 you can make condition that is 'yesterday'..

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the default timezone to your timezone?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

**Remember to change America/Los_Angeles to your location.

See [http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php](http://php.net) for more info.

Comment: Timezones don't matter when dealing strictly with timestamps.